# Extreme lat and lon for ellipse on sphere

Tags: geometry

I have 2 focal points of ellipse defined on a sphere: $F_1 = (q_1, p_1)$ and $F_2 = (q_2, p_2)$ and length of major axis $2a$. $R$ of a sphere is 1.

$q_1, q_2$ are latitudes

$p_1, p_2$ are longitudes

I need to find 4 points:

- point on ellipse with max latitude
- point on ellipse with min latitude
- point on ellipse with max longitude
- point on ellipse with min longitude

I tried to convert points to vectors and use a property that sum of angles 
$$\sphericalangle F_1OP + \sphericalangle F_2OP$$ is constant for each $P$ on ellipse, but it lead me nowhere. Any idea how it can be solved?

Comment: What is an ellipse on a sphere?

Comment: Define an ellipse as the locus of points which is a constant summed distance 
 away from two focal points, whenever the distance is calculated as the
shortest path along the surface of the sphere. I believe this turns out to be the intersection of a cylinder and a sphere.

Comment: Alas @Narlin, I do not think it is that simple.  I believe that the problem is soluble with spherical trig but I will need a bigger block of time to formulate an answer.

Comment: As @Narlin mentioned ellipse is the locus of points which is a constant summed distance away from two focal points.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Can you give me a clue how to approach this problem, maybe I will be able to find the answer by myself.

Answer (score 1):

A **partial answer** based on a comment:

Let $A, B$ be two points on the sphere (Earth) with radius taken as unity.  Define $p(A), q(A)$ as the latitude and longitude of $A$ on the Earth, analogously for other points.  Define $N$ as the North Pole with $p(N)=+\pi/2, q(N)$ arbitrary.

Draw $\triangle ABN$.  Then $|AN|=\pi/2-p(A), |BN|=\pi/2-p(B), |\angle N|=\pm (q(A)-q(B))$.  Now from the Law of Cosines

$\cos(|AB|)=\sin(p(A))\sin(p(B))+\cos(p(A))\cos(p(B))\cos(q(A)-q(B))$.

(As an exercise you may want to derive the same formula replacing $N$ with $S$ where$p(S)=-\pi/2$. Use the identity $\sin(\pi/2+\theta)=\sin(\pi/2-\theta)$.) Use this formula for the distance from any point on the ellipse to the foci, adding up the inverse cosines to equal the major axis.

Good luck!